# Toggle button to occlude geometry missing

Tags: selection-tools, geometry

I cannot see this button anymore, even though I am in edit mode.

Is it possible to hide or delete it accidentally? I need this button back pretty badly, since I dont want to select nearby geometry that would normally be hidden.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean this button?

[image]

It only shows up when you are in Solid View or higher. If you are in wireframe mode, it will not show up because it cannot compute the occlusion.

Comment: If you still can't see it, try middle-click draging the 3d view header bar to pan its contents.

Comment: yeah thats the one. didnt realize that about wireframe mode. will make selecting vertices trickier.